# SparkJava on API Level prior to v26

Tags: java, android, jetty, httpserver, spark-java

I wrote a simple proxy using [SparkJava 2.3.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.3.0) which uses [Jetty 9.4.4.v20170414](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.4.4.v20170414). Unfortunately, the proxy worked fine on Android 8 (API 26), but it wasn't on Android 7 (API 24).

The clue I got was a stack trace:

```
art  I  Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response>: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method withInitial(Ljava/util/function/Supplier;)Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal; in class Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.ThreadLocal' appears in /system/framework/core-oj.jar)
     I    at void org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.<clinit>() (Response.java:77)
     I    at void org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.<init>(org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector, org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration, org.eclipse.jetty.io.EndPoint, org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpTransport) (HttpChannel.java:94)
     I    at void org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelOverHttp.<init>(org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection, org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector, org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration, org.eclipse.jetty.io.EndPoint, org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpTransport) (HttpChannelOverHttp.java:69)
     I    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelOverHttp org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.newHttpChannel() (HttpConnection.java:127)
     I    at void org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.<init>(org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration, org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector, org.eclipse.jetty.io.EndPoint, org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpCompliance, boolean) (HttpConnection.java:102)
     I    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.Connection org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory.newConnection(org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector, org.eclipse.jetty.io.EndPoint) (HttpConnectionFactory.java:85)
     I    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.Connection org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager.newConnection(java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel, org.eclipse.jetty.io.EndPoint, java.lang.Object) (ServerConnector.java:482)
     I    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.EndPoint org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel, java.nio.channels.SelectionKey) (ManagedSelector.java:420)
     I    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.EndPoint org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1600(org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector, java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel, java.nio.channels.SelectionKey) (ManagedSelector.java:61)
     I    at void org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run() (ManagedSelector.java:599)
     I    at void org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(java.lang.Runnable) (QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
     I    at void org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run() (QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
     I    at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:761)
```

It looks that Google added in API 26 a Java 8 compliant method `ThreadLocal<S> ThreadLocal.withInitial (Supplier<? extends S> supplier)` ([link](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html?hl=EN-AU#withinitial)), and this method is utilised by Jetty.

Is there a way of using SparkJava on Android API prior to 26?
Or using a previous version of Jetty? I tried to downgrade SparkJava but it still was using quite new releases of Jetty.